# Как использовать функционал windows.h для определения возможности редактировать и создавать файлы

Tags: c++, windows, файлы, файловая-система

Как использовать функционал `windows.h` для определения возможности редактировать и создавать файлы?

В ОС Windows нельзя создавать файлы  с названиями `con`, `com1` и т.д.
Нельзя редактировать системные файлы самой ОС от лица пользователя без прав администратора. Как программно задать невозможность создать/редактировать такие файлы с помощью функционала `windows.h`?
Я писал похожую функцию, но в ней не смог полностью ограничить пользователя.

```
bool is_path_good(std::string path)
{
    std::string not_allowed[] = { "<", ">", "/", "|", "?", "*", };
    std::string not_allowed_names[] = { "con", "prn", "aux", "nul", "com1", "com2", "com3", "com4", "com5", "com6", "com7",
                                        "com8", "com9", "lpt1", "lpt2", "lpt3", "lpt4", "lpt5", "lpt6", "lpt7", "lpt8", "lpt9" };
    bool not_in_list = true;
    std::string path_copy = path;
    for (int i = 0; i != path.length(); ++i)
    {
        path_copy[i] = tolower(path[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != 6; ++i)
    {
        if (std::string::npos != path_copy.find(not_allowed[i])) return false;;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != 22; ++i)
    {
        if (path_copy == not_allowed_names[i]) return false;;
    }
    return true;
}
```

На путь `con` вернётся `false`
На что-то такое: `C:\my\text.txt` вернётся `true`

**Есть ли в `windows.h` более полный функционал для обработки пути к создаваемому/редактируемому файлу?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft [предлагает](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#return-value) вызвать GetLastError() после попытки создания файла, функция вернет NULL(пустой DWORD забитый нулями) если всё прошло нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно говоря, вся работа с исключительными ситуациями в WinAPI и проверка "А всё ли так?" реализуется через вызов GetLastError() чуть ли не повсеместно. Исключением является COM с его кодом ошибки HRESULT, его писали позже. Это связано с тем, что само WinApi реализовано на языке программирования Си и бросать исключения не умеет.